# Visual Studio 2022 - Disable just auto browser refresh while hot reload being enabled

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, hot-reload

I'm developing an ASP app on Visual Studio 2022. Hot Reload saves a lot of time but it has an additional feature on Visual Studio that automatically refresh the browser after applying changes. As most of my app requests are Ajax based, I can resend a request without refreshing the page while refreshing the page has some side effect like clearing the form inputs.

I want Hot Reload to be enabled but only disable this browser automatic refresh.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this page with a fix for this: https://peaku.co/questions/4731-como-deshabilitar-el-enlace-del-navegador-en-aspnet-core-(net-6,-vs-2022)

Just tested it in my own .NET Core app and the browser no longer refreshes on file save, but you can leave Hot Reload enabled which still functions normally.